# Magento Embedded ERP custom attribute import shelf_location

Tags: magento, import, attributes, erp

I use Magento and Embedded ERP module. Multiples attributes are related to Embedded ERP as "shelf_location" in table "cataloginventory_stock_item
" (contains "product_id", not "sku").

I want import products but "shelf_location" is not an EAV attribute, just a column added by Embedded ERP. Neither advanced profile in Magento is available for this. How could I do it? It is possible to add in the table "cataloginventory_stock_item" from CSV custom column ?